# Vite sends root index.html content when static html is requested

Tags: vite, rollup, rollupjs

I'm using the charting library from TradingView, which requires static HTML to be loaded inside an iFrame. I've placed the static html inside the `public` folder:

```
/public/charting_library/en-tv-chart.b555c6a4.html
```

And it is accessed via:

```
localhost:3000/charting_library/en-tv-chart.b555c6a4.html
```

However, when requesting the above URL, the contents are that of the root `index.html`, not that of the static asset.

How can I get Vite to route the HTML asset correctly here?

Comment: What's interesting is that curling a static HTML works fine, so I can only assume the browser is sending a different header which causes it to return the 304

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using Vite middleware:

```
function chartingLibrary(): PluginOption {
  return {
    apply: 'serve',
    configureServer(server: ViteDevServer) {
      return () => {
        server.middlewares.use(async (req, res, next) => {
          if (req.originalUrl?.includes('/charting_library/') && req.originalUrl?.includes('html')) {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.write(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, `public/${req.originalUrl}`)));
            res.end();
          }

          next();
        });
      };
    },
    name: 'charting-library',
  };
}
```

And then in the config:

```
{
  // ...
  plugins: [
    // ...
    chartingLibrary(),
  ],
}
```